# Reading Waveform from microphone - signal shape problem

Tags: audio-processing

I read 2kHz sinusoidal signal that I generate using youtube and mobile phone by shotgun microphone and sound card in my laptop. Results (python):

[image]

[image]

[image]

But why are the values zero at the beginning and then the values are very large and around 8 [s] the signal has a "good" shape?

Comment: because that's how the recorded sound is, after all analog and digital signal processing. It's not clear why anything of this would not be "good", or expected. Could you explain what you think is wrong?

Comment: I gave a 2kHz sine wave as the input signal. The all waveform should be as shown in Figure 2. But as we can see in the beginning from 1[s] to 7[s], the wave has  different amplitude.

Comment: It's probably caused by AGC in the receiver. I've seen audio cards do exactly that when recording.

Comment: How can this problem be solved or avoided in the future? For example, when I am going to buy a new microphone or another card. Can a USB card help?

Comment: @MBaz 8 s AGC regulation time seems a bit crass

Comment: @user46845 you'd really want to make sure there's no hidden "audio enhancement" feature running in your OS, and you're getting what is actually recorded. A quick Linux boot from a bootable USB drive might answer that. Also, why stop the recording at all? Your software could just start recording long before you need it, and just drop the samples on the floor until you actually want something – then the 8s of bad stuff are all long past. Getting samples from the soundcard and ignoring them costs so little CPU power for a modern laptop, it'll hardly be measurable in battery time.

Comment: by the way, there's better ways than youtube to make your phone emit tones. Generate an audio file with audacity or python and play it; use the Phyfox app to generate arbitrary tones; anything but youtube would also remove a source of online error.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I missed that; 8 s _is_ a bit long. I would still run some tests to see if AGC is affecting the results; some sound card drivers are really bad.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. First of all, I would like to add that I collect data on a virtual machine.  My main system is Wndows 10. I also have Wndows 10 on the virtual machine. As of today, I will be collecting data longer, e.g. up to 20s. Generating a signal using the application and using Ubuntu is also a very good idea :)

Comment: Try listening to your recording. Does that sound like  a steady state sine wave or is some other crap in there?

Comment: I used the Phyfox application and the graph is the same. I will try to do the same but with Ubuntu in a virtual machine and with Ununtu bootable from USB

Comment: I checked the sound cart of the Ubuntu from a pendrive and the situation is the same.

Comment: When I am using phyphox and signal form youtube the wave is ok.